# Thunderbird, TLS and ubuntu 20.04

Tags: thunderbird, tls

I have ubuntu 20.04. After some uncertain updates (but nothing big), my thunderbird stop working. I have several IMAP servers, but on all I am getting same error:

The base socket has problems processing the connection to xxxx:993: Error during startup SSL: >error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
I try reinstall thunderbird, remove apparmor, remove snap, reconnect to mailboxes again, but the error is the same.

Is there anybody with the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

what versions of TLS speak your IMAP servers? TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 or 1.3?
Ubuntu 20.4 don't support unsecure TLS versions like TLS 1.0 and 1.1.

Maybe this informations helps, too:

https://blog.surgut.co.uk/2019/08/how-to-disable-tls-10-and-tls-11-on.html

Regards

Comment: Thank you, for advice. I try to resolve TLS version with command:
```openssl s_client -showcerts -connect sk-mail-1.axfone.eu:993```

And i've got response:
```CONNECTED(00000003)
140576329438528:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1941:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 86 bytes and written 318 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated```

Comment: That means, that OpenSSL on your Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't support the TLS on the server. If you maintain the server in your example, you should care about it. With the website https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest you can test the server's  TLS. The grade of this server is C. The server only supports TLS 1.0 and all ciphers are weak, for example TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA.  The Diffie-Hellman key is weak and there is no  Forward Secrecy. For my opinion someone have to care about the IMAP servers. TLS 1.0 is from 1999. TLS 1.1 is from 2006. It use SHA-1 which is broken.

Comment: Thank you #moep. The server is not my, I will have to send it to my provider.

Comment: Is it possible to manually enable TLS1.0 on ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: open `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and change it:

[system_default_sect]
...
# MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
MinProtocol = TLSv1.0

Maybe you have to replace some ciphers.

Comment: Thank you. I did it, but I have still same problem. I found, that the problem has only thunderbird. When I use Claw Mails or Geary, than everything is working fine. I am helpless. I try to reinstall Thunderbird several times, but with no help... :-(

Comment: Take a loot into Thunderbird settings in about:config. See here http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.min